# EOS 6 old printer cannot be removed

Tags: settings, printer

I made a fresh install of EOS from 5.1 to 6 keeping my home partition. Now I have the problem, that I see an outdated printer in the printers settings that I can't remove.

Any idea where this entry might be stored?

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Same issue here. I added a few configurations trying to get my printer to work (never worked). Beyond that, all the configurations are stuck there in Printers panel can't be deleted.